# passing blocks around in javascript without lengthy function syntax

Tags: javascript

In my testing code, I'm getting a lot of things that look like this:

```
test.truth(function(){return myTest.isDef('')});
```

Where a majority of the line there is just the function boilerplate. Is there a way to reduce that, so that I can have a syntax more like:

```
test.truth { myTest.isDef('') }
```

as one would do in Scala?

Of course, ideally this is highly browser compatible.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for concise syntax, you may want to give [CoffeeScript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) a look.

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry. Javascript has array literals - `[]` and object literals - `{}`, but function literals are only possible using `function() { }` syntax

Answer (score 0):

You could use eval

```
function testtrutheval(someobject, evaltext)
{
   test.truth(function {  eval("someobject." + evaltext);});
}
```

And then write

```
Testtrutheval(mytest,"isdef('')");
```

I hope i got the syntax right, its been 8 years sinc i did javascript.